# ngRoute controller form partial view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Setting up ngRoute throughout my application creates a problem. The controllers used in many views are dependant on script taken from the database in the ASP.NET controllers. Here's an example:

Angular App

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/Template/:id", {
                templateUrl: function(arg) { return "/User/Template/Details/" + arg.id },
                controller: "FormController"
            });                
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix("!");
    }]);
```

Razor view Details.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('triggered');
        angular.module("app").controller("FormController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
            alert("not triggered");
            $scope.xyz = 1;
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<div id="template-details" class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="FormController" ng-cloak>
    <span>{{xyz}}</span>
</div>
```

It loads the view just fine, except it doesn't initiate the controller (with the ViewBag code). The script block executes just fine (tested with the first alert()).

Comment: Check browser console for any errors.

Comment: It says the FormController is not a function and got undefined

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to keep in mind, when you get `controller is undefined`:

1. Make sure your `Angular App` is loaded before you call the `FormController` script
2. Make sure your `FormController` div is inside `ng-app="app"` `div`.
3. Make sure you are loading `ng-route` after `angular`.

I have created a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3821/) from what you have provided and it works fine.

Comment: Hey Zaki, thanks for the answer. However, you define the controller inside the .js file, but I want to load the controller inside the .html view. Moreover, the controller contents are dynamically generated from a database using the ASP.NET MVC controller. As for your things to keep in mind. Within AngularJS routing isn't the whole point that the app only gets initiated once? So I think it is loaded before. The controller is definately inside the app. How can I check if I load ngRoute at the right time? Because I have set the config inside the application start (which I think is fine)

Comment: It doesn't matter where you load the content from also doesn't matter where the controller is kept js/html - although from maintainability point it should be in separated. As for ngRoute in mvc use script section tags to make sure it is loaded before.